# How do I get Bootstrap modals to close in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I've got a standard Bootstrap modal with a regular old close button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

It works fine if I run as a standard app, and even if I package in Electron as a desktop app.  However, when bundled into Cordova, the modal exhibits odd behavior.  It opens fine (on an href click), but then refused to close by any normal means ("x" button, the above close button, or even background clicks).  It seems like it freezes up, but not totally.  If I use my overall container to move to a different page and back, the original screen is reset to the modal being hidden.  If I remove the data-dismiss from the button and attach an onclick, the onclick never gets called when in Cordova.  If I do the same on native or Electron it *does* get called.

So, appears there's something different about Bootstrap modals in Cordova that I'm just not getting?

Comment: Currently i dnt know that why its not closing but second thing about onclick event that you have to bind onclick event in device ready function then you will able to call it in cordova .

Comment: @HassanALi I presume you mean like https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/victorsh/entry/apache_cordova_and_jquery?lang=en ?  Quite informative, but still has not allowed me to get it working for some reason.  Know of any working samples I could look at for comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a known issue.  Bootstrap and Cordova are not compatible.